# M-g g (a.k.a M-x goto-line) acting weird

Tags: elisp, emacs24

Emacs noob (sort of) here.  I'm getting unexpected behavior from the goto-line command.  The wording of the manual seems imprecise.  I'm assuming the phrase "move to line LINE..." means "set point to line LINE".  So my interpretation of the manual's entry on goto-line is that it is supposed to set mark at the current location of point and then move point to the line specified by the argument you enter.  Is this correct?  Because what is happening instead is that, yes, it does set mark at the current location successfully (which I don't care about since I can set mark myself very easily if I want to) but then it sets point at the beginning of the buffer instead of where I specified.  Is this what goto-line is supposed to do?  Am I misunderstanding either the manual or the purpose of this command?

The activity I'm engaged in is reading the Emacs Lisp manual and evaluating expressions in it.  I have line numbers turned on in the left margin, and I would like to be able to simply do M-g g LINE-NUMBER, C-e, C-x C-e and see how the form evaluates.  But instead, I have to do this klutzy routine of subtracting current point line number from target line number and then doing M-DIFFERENCE C-n. Or I just C-nnnnnnn...or C-pppppp... or even use the mouse, which is the type of slow and clumsy navigation I'm trying to get away from by using Emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, `goto-line` in an Info buffer is working on the source rather than the rendered outcome.

(If you visit the `elisp.info` file, you'll see where the real line numbers are coming from.)

Unfortunately that doesn't help you (or anyone, I suspect), but it does explain why the feature doesn't work as expected.

You could `M-x report-emacs-bug` and propose that this be changed to work the way people would expect it to work.

If you're using Emacs 26 and its native `display-line-numbers-mode` then you can customize the `display-line-numbers-widen` option to prevent line numbers changing when buffers are narrowed, in which case you'll be able to use the number you can see with `goto-line`.

Comment: Thank you very much.  The information about elisp.info was especially helpful.  Given that I don't like the concern slush introduced by the fact that this command also sets mark, I might just write my own simplified version of this functionality.  Maybe I'll call it goto-line-number, and then offer to share it.

Yes, I noticed that Emacs comes with built-in functionality for users to report bugs and general weirdness back to the developers within Emacs itself.  I love it.  That's my kind of thinking!

Comment: FWIW, the *reason* for pushing to the mark ring automatically (which happens with lots of commands that move point by some arbitrary value) is so that you can return to where you came from simply by popping the mark again with `C-u C-SPC`

Comment: Thanks again.  Your FWIW has helped me to better understand how things are normally done in Emacs.